# How to find (and install) the pandas version which is compatible with numpy 1.19.2?

Tags: pip, conda, apple-m1

I've been fighting for too long trying to install tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-addons on a MacM1 (inside specific conda environments), without success.
Thus, I am trying to figure out which libraries are clashing.
I realised that tensorflow-macos 2.6 requires numpy 1.19.2, but when I try to install pandas (which I also need) numpy gets updated to 1.21.
My questions are:

- how can I find a pandas version compatible with numpy 1.19.2
- how should I install it? pip/conda?

Comment: Tell Conda what you want - it will listen ;)  E.g., `conda create -n foo python=3.8 numpy=1.19.2 pandas`

Comment: thanks. But is there a way to find a compatibility matrix between pandas and numpy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a direct way to get a compatibility matrix, but you can pull down all the info on `pandas` packages in your channels and filter for the `numpy` requirements. Something like:

```bash
conda search --info pandas | grep -E '(^version|numpy)'
```

gives output like:

```bash
version     : 0.17.0
  - numpy 1.10*
version     : 0.17.0
  - numpy 1.10*
version     : 0.17.0
  - numpy 1.10*
version     : 0.17.0
  - numpy 1.11*
...
version     : 1.3.3
  - numpy >=1.19.2,<2.0a0
version     : 1.3.4
  - numpy >=1.18.5,<2.0a0
version     : 1.3.4
  - numpy >=1.19.5,<2.0a0
version     : 1.3.4
  - numpy >=1.18.5,<2.0a0
version     : 1.3.4
  - numpy >=1.19.5,<2.0a0
```

But, as commented, the idiomatic usage is to explicitly specify your requirements when creating your environment, like:

```bash
conda create -n myenv python=3.8 numpy=1.19.2 pandas
```

That is, tell Conda everything you want at the outset and it will listen to your needs.

Comment: 2 further questions if I may: 1- is it possible to use conda search in a specific channel?; 2- when I try to do "conda create -n myenv python=3.8 numpy=1.19.2 pandas pyfftw ipykernel cython" I get too many incompatibilities that conda can't solve. How can I proceed in this case?

Comment: @MrT77 not sure why I missed the follow-up - sorry about that. 1) search channel with `conda search <channel>::<package>`, which restricts looking for "package" in "channel"; 2) Try using Mamba instead - on average I find it provides more precise identification of where conflicts originate.